# In Regr_slope for snowflake why are windows frames not supported

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a query that I am trying to persist into a table fore users that has 240 million rows and am looking to include a rolling three year beta on the data.
The original query self joined would be:

```
SELECT
    ibm.trading_item_id,
    ibm.primary_exchange_ticker,
    ibm.date,
    REGR_SLOPE(
        ibm_lagging.USD_PRICE_CLOSE_1D_RT,
        ibm_lagging.SPX_1D_RT
    ) AS spx_beta_3y
FROM
    ibm
    LEFT JOIN ibm ibm_lagging ON ibm.trading_item_id = ibm_lagging.trading_item_id
    AND ibm.date >= ibm_lagging.date
    AND dateadd(year, -3, ibm.date) <= ibm_lagging.date
GROUP BY
    ibm.trading_item_id,
    ibm.primary_exchange_ticker,
    ibm.date
HAVING
    count(*) >= 3 * 250 -- sufficient # of trading days in a year to make this reasonable
ORDER BY
```

The issue is because this is 240 million rows in the base query with the self join I am looking at approximately 750*240 million rows which is not viable to run. Therefore I'd want to use a windows frame but for some reason that is not catered for in the regr_slope function when using a partition by. I think I have a manual workaround but my question is why is it that this would not be catered for. I am worried that by doing it manually I have made an error in my assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first point to note is even if it did support a window frame, that window frames of Snowflake only allow for number of rows, which is a hard coded rolling window, verse a dynamic window (dates in range X) as you have in this problem. Unless you know you have exactly one row per day, then you can use the fixed row logic.

So you allow for dynamic time based method you seems you want, you would need to use a UDTF, so that you can have "arbitrary" carry, but all the while not overloading the memory limits of the JavaScript stack.

If we assume you have fixed data, thus a fix rows solution is valid, to answer the WHY? [REGR_SLOPE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regr_slope.html) is defined as `COVAR_POP(x,y) / VAR_POP(x)`, [VAR_POP](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/var_pop.html) supports windows frames, but [COVAR_POP](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/covar_pop.html) does not. So this would explain  that, but COVAR_POP is made of SUM and COUNT and those do support window frames, so you could manually roll fixed row versions of that, but as you say that sounds risky.. as you note.

Comment: Thanks. Assuming a fixed windows frame. Just out of curiosity why would cov_pop not support the windows frame? My guess is that if the var_pop(x) is 0 then those rows would need to be excluded as regr_slope would be undefined. This would not be apparent in covar_pop on its own

Comment: my first guess, is given the function is the "variance of the population" aka all the known data, only sampling part of that data, sounds rather non-population to me. At face value that would be my  big why. But my first why would be, because no body has asked for it. Which when I considered why would nobody have asked for it, I suspect it's because it actually does not make sense. But then COVAR_SAMP does not support window functions ether.. so maybe we are back to asking for it.